# Is it possible to stream a tablet screen to desktop via bluetooth to a PC?

Tags: bluetooth, screen-sharing

This way you could give a presentation (and make annotations), show movies on your tablet and stream it to your PC/laptop which is connected with bluetooth (in e.g. a classroom) with no need to go to the PC.

Has anybody used this setup?

As a teacher it would make a smartboard out of my tablet (which i would buy for this purpose, amongst few others) and a simple bluetooth dongle which I could plug in the school PC.

Looks simple to me, but probably isn't as simple as I imagine?

I'm even prepared to pay a fee for an app if this is available.

Comment: Bluetooth is not a viable thing to use because its quite a limited range and more importantly the transfer size for each block of data in transmission is way smaller than using Wifi/Ethernet for internet browsing etc! I know its not the answer you're looking for! but why not use wifi?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a way to display your tablet screen other than some sort of display adapter. Things like [this](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?sugexp=chrome,mod%3D2&q=wireless+hdmi+transmitter&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=11350074167333732003&sa=X&ei=JRfrT9WuHYOu8ASSrZ3dBQ&ved=0CIgBEPMCMAQ) with the receiver would allow you to do it wirelessly, but they get mighty expensive.

Additionally, I do not believe bluetooth is designed as a "Display out" port, so to say, and I am hard pressed to believe it would be easy to do this, beside the fact that you may need to write that yourself.

I would recommend something like [Splashtop Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.splashtop.remote.pad&hl=en). *This does not display your tablet screen on the PC*  but **allows you to see and control your PC screen from your tablet**. So you could not share your tablet screen, but you could still walk around the classroom with your tablet and control what is being projected to the screen.

Also, and I don't know if this works over bluetooth, but you could try [the Android Screencast Project](http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/). Maybe it has what you need!

I know it's not the solution you're looking for, but hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I too would like to do this, but mainly so that I can handwrite text and mathematics on slides presented on my laptop in PowerPoint.

I tried Splashtop Remote as suggested by another responder. While this is seems to be an excellent tool for remotely controlling your computer, the latency and slightly unreliable nature of the connection means that it is not good enough to transmit readable handwriting.

The other option I'm considering (which you might too) would be to just plug the tablet directly into the projection system (assuming that's what you're using), i.e. do everything from the tablet. There are several options ([Keynote](https://www.apple.com/mac/keynote/), [Polaris Office](https://www.polarisoffice.com) etc., depending on your hardware) for presentation software that will run on tablets.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [Screen Stream](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobzapp.screenstream.trial) on Android. It works great!

Answer (score 0):

No need for internet or bluetooth. All that's needed is a wireless router and a smart tv. Once your handheld device and smart tv are linked to the wireless router, then you'll have a network setup to stream from your device to the smart tv. Using Google's home app.

Answer (score -1):

There is software that I am looking at called SmartClass by Radix software.  Do a search on Youtube and you will see it in action. :-)  I have been in contact with the software developer and we will be going with the application if we get classroom tablets.

Comment: "Do a search" is a very poor answer (arguably not an answer at all). If you know of software that solves the problem presented in the question, please do at least a little bit of legwork and provide a link in your answer.

Comment: Excuse me, but I believe I stated the name of the software.  The video will give Peter an idea of what the software does, including screen streaming.  I do not see how that is not an answer.